# Invalid hex characters in region list in hbase shell

Tags: hbase

We have a hBase table with a Java long as the key. The rows are added by:

```
Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(longVal));
```

When I display the regions for the table in hbase shell I see non hex values displayed:

```
scan 'hbase:meta',{FILTER=>"PrefixFilter('table_name')"}  
...  
START => '\x00\x00\x00\xB3t\XAE\x1E'
```

> 1. Shouldn't these all be valid hex?

I am not sure how this happens.

> 2. Is there a know bug in hBase that would cause display issues?

The table is corrupt and we are trying to recover as much data as we can.

> 3. Could this be caused by the corruption?

hbase hbck currently says the table is OK, by the way.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the 't' in the key above should be valid hex digits. The key is too short otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong as long as you are writing/reading your data with long rowkeys. Hbase shell can show byte data strange but it does not mean it stores data wrong. Shell basically trying to show every thing as string.